# How to draw random points from KML Multigeometry or at least Polygons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kml, geo, geography

I would like to draw random coordinates inside KML countries shapes made from Multigeometry & Polygons. I tried to get random points of states from different online APIs, such as [3geonames](https://api.3geonames.org), but they sometimes do not coincide with KML boundaries especially for island states that fails the initialisation of my phylogeographic analysis.

The task of finding internal points inside the figure contour is trivial. So I do not want to reinvent the wheel & am sure that there should be any good way to do this in python directly from kml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not discovered a prepared solutions that is strange for me. Nonetheless, there are some convenient ways to work with geodata in *KML* using `geopandas` & `shapely`.

```
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

some_map = gpd.read_file(fr'some_map.kml', driver='KML')

def getRandomPoint(map: gpd.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    
    def generateRandomPointOfBox() -> shapely.geometry.point.Point:
        return Point(uniform(minx, maxx), uniform(miny, maxy))
    
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = map.bounds.values[0]
    point = generateRandomPointOfBox()
    while not map.contains(point).values:
        point = generateRandomPointOfBox()
    return (point.x, point.y)
```

As a result, we can see that this works:

```
points = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(getRandomPoint(some_map)) for _ in range(300)])
points.plot(ax=some_map.plot(), color="red", markersize=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution in [this](https://medium.com/the-data-journal/a-quick-trick-to-create-random-lat-long-coordinates-in-python-within-a-defined-polygon-e8997f05123a) post by Aayush Sethi, he lets you insert the polygon directly in the script. I made some minor changes.

```
import numpy as np
import random
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

poly = Polygon([(37.75850848099701, -122.50833008408812), (37.75911919711413, -122.49648544907835),
                (37.751620611284935, -122.4937388670471), (37.74863453749236, -122.50742886185911)])


# Defining the randomization generator
def polygon_random_points(poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    points = []
    while len(points) < num_points:
        random_point = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if random_point.within(poly):
            points.append(random_point)
    return points


# Choose the number of points desired. This example uses 20 points.
points = polygon_random_points(poly, 20)

# Printing the results.
for p in points:
    print(p.x, ",", p.y)
```